# Java Enums with different number of parameters

Tags: java, jpa, enums

I want to create an enum that represents various JPA NamedQueries. Each query though may have a different number/type of parameters. So I when I want to refer to the query / query placeholder I can do something like the following:

```
Entity.Queries.FIND_PERSON_BY_NAME_AND_ADDRESS.toString(); //gets the Query itself

Entity.Queries.Query1.FIND_PERSON_BY_NAME_AND_ADDRESS.PLACEHOLDER_NAME ; //gets the string of the placeholder "name"

Entity.Queries.Query1.FIND_PERSON_BY_NAME_AND_ADDRESS.PLACEHOLDER_ADDRESS;  //gets the String of the placeholder "address"
```

I want to do this so when I create the named queries I can do the following

```
Query q = entitiManager.createNamedQuery(Entity.Queries.FIND_PERSON_BY_NAME_AND_ADDRESS.toString); 
q.setParameter(Entity.Queries.Query1.FIND_PERSON_BY_NAME_AND_ADDRESS.PLACEHOLDER_ADDRESS, address);
```

Is this possible with enums, or should I just use final constants in private static classes or something?

Comment: You shouldn't use toString() for code purposes - in this case to get the HQL. Call it 'getHql()` or whatever instead

Comment: Since an enum defines a type with a limited value set, ask yourself whether you will ever use `Entity.Queries` as a return type, field type, parameter type, or generic type argument.  If not, regular constants are more appropriate.